# Calling Outlook API to Add event to outlook calendar using ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, outlook-restapi

I need to Add an event from my database to outlook calendar for which I have been trying to make an ajax call to the outlook auth API first which looks like this

```
$scope.authorizeOutlook = function () {

    let redirect = 'http://localhost:51419';
    let clientId = 'xxx';

    var authData = 'client_id=' + clientId + '&response_type=code&redirect_uri=' + redirect + '&response_mode=query&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fcalendars.readwrite%20&state=12345';
    debugger
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
        type: 'POST',
        host: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com',
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        contentLength: "600",
        data: authData,
        success: function (response) {
            debugger;
            alert(response.status);
            //alert("success");
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.status);
            //alert("fail");
        }
    });
}
```

But I am getting response status as 0. What does that mean? Where am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Oauth2.0, you need to add " token-type: Bearer ".

Reference from:

[Get access tokens to call Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_overview)

Comment: I have been following up with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow and there is no parameter as 'token_type'. I think " token-type: Bearer " is what we get in response.

Comment: Maybe this link will help for you: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2014/03/25/using-oauth2-to-access-calendar-contact-and-mail-api-in-office-365-exchange-online/

Comment: You could try to add "token-type: Bearer" in your authData. I think you will have a right reponse.

Comment: it doesn't work, I am still getting response status as 0